# CDF of Random Symmetric Alternating Geometric Series

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $(Y_n)$ be IID RVs taking values $1$ and $-1$ with equal probabilities. Will $\sum_n Y_n/2^n$ converge almost surely? If yes, then compute the distribution of the limit?

**My Trials:**

It is easy to see
$$
\sum_n |Y_n|/2^n \leq \sum_n 1/2^n < \infty.
$$
Hence $\sum_n Y_n/2^n$ converges almost surely as it converges absolutely. I am not so sure about how to deal with the computation of the distribution: Fix $t \in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\sum_{n = 1} ^\infty \frac{Y_n}{2^n} \leq t) &= \mathbb{P}(\limsup_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1} ^k \frac{Y_n}{2^n}) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{j = 1} ^\infty \bigcup_{k = j} ^\infty \{ \sum_{n = 1} ^k \frac{Y_n}{2^n} \leq t \}).
\end{align*}
**How should I proceed from here?**

Comment: You might work out the characteristic function of the sum...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $(X_n)$ are IID RVs taking on values $0,1$ with equal probability, then $\sum_n \frac{X_n}{2^n} \sim \text{Unif}[0,1]$. Notice that $2X_n - 1$ has the same distribution as $Y_n$. Can you express the distribution of your sum in terms of a uniform random variable now?